# Quickbooks Online Banking/WebBrowser Issue

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, quickbooks, accounting, onlinebanking

Ok, so here's what's going on and I think its pretty simple.  We connect to Citibank (I only say this because I don't know if any other institution would exhibit the same behavior) in order to download our reconciliation file.

Yesterday the person who uses quickbooks showed me that Quickbooks is hanging during the download and import process.  But it's hanging at the very beginning of the process.

What Quickbooks seems to do is use Internet Explorer to load up citibank.com... and then the side panels... the login and ... account specific menus don't load.. they just show the progress indication spinning.

I'm thinking that Quickbooks is just using an old form of IE that can't handle newer websites? has anyone experienced even something similar to this issue before.  Any assistance is appreciated.  Thank you,
Bryan

Comment: This question is probably best addressed by Inuit, the makers of QuickBooks because if it is a bug in their software, then they are the only people in a position to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks uses an embedded version of IE for displaying internet content. This can cause some odd problems depending on your internet security settings. It sounds as if you're using Web Connect to get the infomration from the bank, in which case you can usually just log into the bank's website using whatever browser you want and download the file. The bank usually has multiple format types (Quicken, Microsoft Money, QuickBooks,etc.) so make sure you get the .QBO file. You can either import it by double clicking the file, or go to File > Utilities > Import > Web Connect Files

Comment: pretty much confirmed what I was thinking... thank you!